# Hiding keyboard on a text field in mobile/tablets

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

I have a text field which uses bootstrap datepicker plugin.
Text field is as below-

```
<input id="Date" name="Date" type="text" value="">
```

JS code that binds datepicker with it is as follows-

```
 $('#Date').datepicker({
        format: "dd MM, yyyy",
        disableTouchKeyboard: true,
        todayHighlight: true
    });
```

In desktops, it works fine.

I have problem in mobiles and tablets - When user click on this textbox, it shows calendar as well as virtual keyboard.

I want to hide virtual keyboard for this textfield for mobile and tablets whenever it gets forcus.

How can I do that?

Comment: i was getting the same issue once before and i solved it by typing 
$('#Datet').blur(); let me know if it wokrs

Comment: Cool! This worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i was getting the same issue once before and i solved it by typing

`$('#Datet').blur();`

just in other case it will not help you tro to use so this is a pure JS code to handle it

```
document.activeElement.blur();
```